# building eager loading query with a variable

Tags: laravel, eloquent, lumen

Currently building out an API. Using Lumen and Fractal. One of the cool things with fractal is the ability to pass in includes via the query string like ?foo=bar,mar,par

But now when it comes to building my query i want to take advantage of Eloquents eager loading. So ideally this query if using the example above would be:

```
->with(['bar','mar','par'])
```

But fumbling over how i get from my query string to building that query. 
Obviously I am passing this through a validator to make sure whatever is being passed is legit so if someone passed 'par123' that would fail as i dont have that table.

and i cant pass in the following:

```
$example = 'bar','mar','par';
->with([$example]);
```

any thoughts on how to build out that query with out manually checking each parameter passed and building a unique query for every scenario...

Comment: I suggest looking at `dingo/api` as it'll automatically handle `league/fractal` eager loading for you

Comment: not seeing how that package does that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I have never used fractal but this solution will work with Lumen.

```
$params = $request->input('foo'); // will give you 'bar,mar,par'
```

now you need to split this string into an array of strings for your various models to be eagerloaded

```
$paramArray = explode(',', $params); // ['bar', 'mar', 'par']

$results = Model::find('foo')->with($paramArray)->get();
```

Comment: hmm tried this and it was not working ... let me revisit.

Comment: I was not passing through the exact method that represents the relationship. I was just using a common variable xyz whatever. has to be exact. now it works! thanks man.